# ¿Cómo crear una alarma en Android?

Tags: android

Estoy intentando crear una alarma en Android cuando le den click a un botón para el mismo día en el que se le da el botón pero para una hora en concreto.

El código que tengo es el siguiente:

```
AlarmManager alarma = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

Calendar cal= Calendar.getInstance();

cal.set(Calendar.MONTH,cal.get(Calendar.MONTH));
cal.set(Calendar.YEAR,cal.get(Calendar.YEAR));
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,cal.get(Calendar.DATE));
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,20);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE,30);

alarma.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),pendingIntent);
```

Sin embargo, tengo un problema a la hora de establecer los parámetros de la alarma. Tengo los dos primeros parámetros establecidos, sin embargo, no consigo establecer el tercero, el `pendingIntent`.

Sinceramente, leyendo la [documentación](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#set(int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) sobre este método en la documentación oficial de Android, tampoco me ha quedado muy claro lo que debería de situar en el tercer parámetro y los ejemplos que he visto en Internet más que ayudarme han ayudado a liarme un poco más.

¿Como podría establecer la alarma correctamente?

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Este código es para activar una Alarma, solo cambia los valores por el tuyo.

```
private AlarmManager alarmMgr;
private PendingIntent alarmIntent;

alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);

// Alarma a las 8:30 a.m.
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 8);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);

// Repeticiones en intervalos de 20 minutos
alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
        1000 * 60 * 20, alarmIntent);
```

Si quieres una explicación más explícita lee [esto](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html).

Answer (score 0):

Todo depende que es lo que quieras hacer cuando se ejecute la alarma. Puede ser que quieras abrir una Actividad, o enviar un broadcast intent para recibirlo en un Broadcast Receiver, o alguna otra cosa

Para abrir una actividad

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityToLaunch.class);
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
```

Para enviar un BroadcastIntent

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction("com.example.app.ACTION");
PendingIntent pI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivityContext(), 0, intent, 0);
```

El pending Intent tiene muchos usos, te dejo la documentacion de PendingIntent para que investigues que mas se puede hacer

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html

Comment: Me gustaría crear una alarma simplemente, como si fuera la alarma del teléfono. Para ello, ¿cuál de las dos opciones tendría que usar? Aunque entiendo que la de crear una nueva actividad no (corrígeme si estoy equivocado).

Comment: El servicio de Alarma, aunque el nombre pueda indicar otra cosa, no es para poner Alarmas como la del reloj de buro. Es para detonar eventos en algún momento especifico en el futuro, dejando que Android gestione cuando se detona. Si tu deseo es hacer específicamente una app de alarmas o recordatorios, necesitas implementar la solución para eso. Puede ser que se abra una nueva actividad que reproduzca música y despliegue la hora de la alarma. O puedes implementar un broadcast receiver que al recibir la acción, levante una notificación, o que se active un servicio, etc.

Comment: Te dejo un tutorial para hacer justamente eso http://javapapers.com/android/android-alarm-clock-tutorial/

Comment: Vale, ahí residía mi fallo principalmente. Pensaba que era alguna configuración del propio Android. Le voy a echar un vistazo más a fondo al PendingIntent aunque en la documentación de Android ya me lo he leído más de una vez y no me queda claro del todo, por lo que mirare en algún otro tutorial. La verdad que no se si es que no acabo de pillar su documentación pero me suele parecer bastante liosa. Gracias por la info, investigaré sobre todo esto en cuanto tenga algo de tiempo. Y cuando consiga hacerla funcionar, te daré la respuesta como aceptada :)