# Ejecutar un script una vez al día en android

Tags: java, android

Tengo una app en la que compruebo en mi servidor si he cambiado la imagen de fondo. 
Actualmente realizo una apetición cada vez que va a la home.

Esto lo quiero cambiar pues no quiero que se realicen tantas peticiones.

Lo que quiero hacer es lo siguiente:

Quiero que solo se compruebe una vez al día. Por ejemplo a las 10 de la mañana. El problema es que si el usuario no se conecta a las 10 exacto no se realiza el script

Mi código es este:

```
CheckUpdateAvailableAsync cuaa = new CheckUpdateAvailableAsync();
try {
    String result = cuaa.execute().get();
    if (result != null) {
        if (!result.trim().equals("")) {
            if (!result.equals("false")) {
                mostrarFondo(result);
            }
            else {
                 mostrarFondoDefecto();
            }
        }
        else {
             mostrarFondoDefecto();
        }
    }
    else {
         mostrarFondoDefecto();
    }
}
catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    mostrarFondoDefecto();
}
```

Comment: Has pensado en hacer un servicio en segundo plano que se quede dormido 24h y al despertar ejecute el script? O tiene que ser a las 10 de la mañana obligatoriamente?

Comment: Lo de las 10 de la mañana es un ejemplo. Tiene que ser una vez al dia mientras el usuario usa la app @PabloSimonDiEstefano

Comment: Tiene que estar utilizando la App? si tiene que estar utilizando la App no te hace falta el servicio pero tampoco puedes asegurar que el usuario vaya a abrir la app todos los días.

Comment: No tiene que ser todos los dias, solo cuando el susuario utilice la app, pero solo una vez el mismo dia @PabloSimonDiEstefano

Comment: Yo ejecutaría el script al abrir la app y escribes la fecha en un fichero de texto. La siguiente vez que abras la app consultas el fichero de texto y comparas con la fecha de hoy, si no es igual, ejecutas el script. El fichero lo sobreescribes ya que sólo te hace falta la última fecha

Comment: Muchas gracias. Si lo pones como respuesta lo valido @PabloSimonDiEstefano

Comment: @AlbertoMier la forma correcta sería usar la clase AlarmManager, cualquier otra opción sería llegar a lo mismo pero de "forma primitiva" hehe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una posible solución que tienes es guardar la última conexión en un fichero de texto.

Cuando entras a la app ejecutamos el script y escribimos en un fichero la fecha actual (no es necesario guardar la hora, símplemente día, mes y año).

La próxima vez que se ejecuta la App, se consulta la fecha guardada en el fichero y se compara con la fecha actual. Si las fecha actual es mayor que la del fichero se ejecuta el script y se reescribe el fichero (se reescribe porque no es necesario guardar todas las fechas, sólo la última), sino no se ejecuta el script.

Es una posibilidad sencilla de implementar pero no es la única.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Para esto se usa precisamente la clase [**AlarmManager**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html), programas la hora y fecha en la cual se ejecutara un proceso, dentro de la clase que extiende de `BroadcastReceiver` en el método `onReceive()` puedes poner el "script" que deseas ejecutar cada día a las 10 de la mañana.

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        mostrarAlgo();

    }

...

}
```

En el mismo sitio tenemos una pregunta acerca de esto:

**[¿Cómo crear una alarma en Android?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/31390/c%C3%B3mo-crear-una-alarma-en-android)**